# WordPress Custom Post Editor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a seriers of pages that will feature "contests" where artists will use a shortcode to link to a youtube video performance of them based on a given theme and users will be able to comment and judge the videos to determine a winner.

I am using a template to present the contest rules and at the bottom of that content, I need to allow a user to create a post and link to a video. I need to "force" the post to a specific tag which I will use to display all of the entries and their comments.

1. Is is possible to add a "New Post" from a Page?
2. Is it possible to force a tag based on a Custom Field on the page?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, that's possible.Take a look at these two guides: http://voodoopress.com/how-to-post-from-your-front-end-with-no-plugin/ and http://wpshout.com/wordpress-submit-posts-from-frontend/
2. You should be able to do that, though I haven't done it myself. But if the purpose of the tag is just to separate these user-submitted posts from other posts, then you'd probably be better of using Custom Post Types, and separating them that way. And yes, you can submit custom post types in the way mentioned in those links above. Just add ‘post_type’=>$customposttype (where $customposttype is the name of your custom post type) to the $post array that you enter into wp_insert_post.